# If "@" is present in json response then navigating it as json path from JS function giver error

Tags: karate

[image: this givers error. But if "@" as a key replaced in json as "at" then working fine]

> this givers error. But if "@" as a key replaced in json as "at" then working fine

Comment: Error as below:

javascript evaluation failed: function(xx){ 
    karate.log('ProximityUnits = ', xx._.GeoInfo.@.ProximityUnits);
   var f = xx._.GeoInfo.@.ProximityUnits;
   karate.log('function response = ', f);
   karate.match(f, 'mi');
 }, <eval>:2:49 Expected ident but found error
    karate.log('ProximityUnits = ', xx._.GeoInfo.@.ProximityUnits);
                                                 ^ in <eval>

Comment: You can access properties through the subscript operator: `obj.prop === obj['prop']`. This is useful in cases like this where reserved symbols are used (a more common example would be a prop name `"hello-world"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved:
var f = xx['_']['GeoInfo']['@']['ProximityUnits'];

Navigate with above in the function as per karate DSL support. Then it will work for "@" also.